# JavaFX Update GUI Before Entering Another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, controller, java-8, fxml

**EDIT:**

I noticed that my question was linked to another. While our goals are similar, the other question's set up is different: they are creating all the GUI aspects of the program within the main class of their program, they are also setting the trigger event of the button press within the start method. Therefore the solution of using the "setOnAction(event->" coupled with Task works. It is a single class program, I was able to make the solution work if I created a new, single class program, this application does not work for me for my situation.

In my set up I am not running this event out of the main class, but out of the Controller class that is linked to my FXML and I have the event that triggers the method already defined. I did not post my entire Controller class as that seemed unnecessary. If there is a way to make the linked question's solution work for my different set up, or a link for guidance that would be stellar. I have looked into the "task" set up, taking from the linked question, but so far have not been able to get it to work successfully as pictured below:

```
    @FXML
private void goForIt(ActionEvent event) 
{
    kickTheBaby();
}

private void kickTheBaby()
{
   java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
   java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());

   statusFld.setOnAction(event -> {statusFld.setText("Running");
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() 
            {
                (new Thread(new EmailCommunication("", currentTimestamp, "START"))).start();
                (new Thread(new DataGathering2())).start();
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(taskFinishEvent -> statusFld.setText(statusFld.getText() 
    + "All done time to sleep..."));
        new Thread(task).start();
    });
}
```

---

I have a program in Java8 using FXML that downloads and parses data. I wish to make the program update the GUI TextField (called "statusFld" here) to say "Running" when I click the start button. Below is the method in the controller that should be responsible for this series of events.

```
 @FXML
private void goForIt(ActionEvent event) 
{
    statusFld.setText("Running!");

    java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
    java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
    (new Thread(new EmailCommunication("", currentTimestamp, "START"))).start();
    (new Thread(new DataGathering2())).start();

}
```

However, when I attempt to run the program the GUI does not visually update and goes straight into the other two threads. So I attempted to utilize the "Platform.runLater()" methodology in one of the other threads by passing the status field to it as so:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> 
 {
    statusFld.setText("Running!");
});
```

But after 20 minutes it had not given a visual update to the GUI. My guess is that this is probably due to the sheer amount of data processing that I am having it do, so who knows what "later" will actually be in this case.

My question is how can I be sure that the GUI visually updates before moving on to the other, very processing intense, threads?

Thank you!

Comment: Edited question to clarify and show further attempts at making things work.